# R: for loop nested

Tags: r, for-loop, nested, nested-loops

I am just getting started with R and I am getting an unexpected result when constructing a nested FOR loop. When I run the sample below I expect it to produce a 40,000 x 1 vector (i.e. start with t1=50 then iterate over t2 from 0 to 1, then t1=51 and iterate t2 for 0 to 1), but instead I get a 200x1 vector.

I apologize for the extremely basic question. I'm just getting started with R and I can not find a straight forward explanation in my searches.

```
t1=seq(50, 150, 0.5) # 200x1 vector
t2=seq(0, 1, 0.005)  # 200x1 vector
   for (i in t1){

   for (j in t2){

   t3=3*t1+t2
 }
 }
```

Comment: I don't know R at all and I would expect the result to be 200x1

Comment: May be you are after something like this `t3[(i- 1)*length(t1) + j ] <- 3 * t1[i] * t2[j]`?

Comment: The body of your loop doesn't use the indices `i` and `j` at all, so it isn't clear what you are trying to do, though building up a 40,000 element vector element by element would be a very bad idea.

Comment: You are over-writing `t3` at each iteration. You need to define something large enough to hold all iterations. However, you aren't even iterating as you don't use `i` or `j` anywhere. You are just computing `3 * t1 + t2` many many times.

Comment: By the way -- your `t1` and `t2` vectors have `201` elements rather than `200`.

Comment: Do you want `3 * (t1 +t2)` or `(3 * t1) + t2`?

Comment: Thank you all. Your answers got me well on my way

Answer (score 1):

maybe something like this:

```
t1 <- seq(50, 150, 0.5) # 200x1 vector
t2 <- seq(0, 1, 0.005)  # 200x1 vector
t3 <- vector(mode="numeric", length=length(t1)*length(t2))
k <- 0
for (i in t1) {
   for (j in t2) {
       t3[k]=3*i+j
       k <- k+1
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it without loops using [expand.grid](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.4.1/topics/expand.grid).

```
g <- expand.grid(t1,t2)
t3 <- 3 * g[,1] + g[,2]
```

Comment: That's still doing the loop, it's just hidden inside the `apply()` call. Much faster would be to use your `g` and then just do `t3 <- 3 * g[,1] + g[,2]`

Answer (score 1):

In similar spirit to John Coleman's answer, `outer()` is a good functions for things like this.

```
## if you want 3 * (t1 +t2)
t3a <- as.vector(outer(t1, t2, `+`)) * 3

g <- expand.grid(t1,t2)
t3b <- 3 * (g[,1] + g[,2])
```

or

```
## if you want 3 * (t1 +t2)
t4a <- as.vector(outer(3*t1, t2, `+`))

g <- expand.grid(t1,t2)
t4b <- 3 * g[,1] + g[,2]
```

Producing the same outputs as in John's answer.

```
> all.equal(t3a, t3b)
[1] TRUE
> all.equal(t4a, t4b)
[1] TRUE
```

`outer()` seems to be a little quicker, even on this small example, presumably because it works on a matrix whereas `expand.grid()` has to form a data frame.